# How can I make a binary for Windows that will make it possible for a non Coder to just get a crash dump which can be fed to gdb?

Tags: c, windows, debugging, gcc

As the title implies: the scenario is a coder with a gdb and a user reporting a crash. Can he get from the user an easy to use memory dump which can be fed to gdb but also not make it hard for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up [Process Dumper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e089ca41-6a87-40c8-bf69-28ac08570b7e) to produce a full dump on any exception or process exit, based on the name of the executable file.

I am assuming Windows due to the title, alter the tags if not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [DrMingw](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/DrMingw) can help.